# How do I pass an object to Adobe ExtendScript from Javascript (Adobe CEP)?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, ecmascript-3

I'm working with [Adobe CEP](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides) (it lets developers create windowed extensions for Adobe CC products).  The bulk of my code is modern JavaScript (the platform uses Chromium 57, Node.js 7.7.4).  *However*, in order to access the DOM, I need to write some functions in Adobe [ExtendScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExtendScript) and execute them from normal JS.  The only way is to execute a script using their provided `csInterface.evalScript(script, callback)`.  `script` has to be a string, which in my case is a function call converted to a string. **I want to be able to pass an object to and from ExtendScript via `evalScript`**, but `evalScript` only takes and returns a string.

Currently, I am passing each object property as its own argument.  This is unwieldy, but it works.

My first though was `JSON.stringify()`, but unfortunately ExtendScript is a dialect of ECMAScript 3, which means **no `JSON.parse()` support**.

I can't just concat the object argument into the script function call, because then the string evaluates to `foo([object Object])`.

I've seen there are functions like `eval()`/`uneval()` or `Object.toSource()`, but those are not supported by Chromium.

Here's an example, similar to my current method:

**functions.js** (ES3/ExtendScript)

```js
function drawCircle(x, y, name) {
    // pick a layer
    var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];

    var diameter = 10;
    var top = y + diameter / 2;
    var left = x - diameter / 2;

    // draw ellipse in layer
    var circle = layer.pathItems.ellipse(top, left, diameter, diameter);

    circle.name = name;
    circle.filled = true;

    return true;
}
```

**app.js** (ES6)

```js
const csInterface = new CSInterface();    // provided by Adobe
async function circle() {
    const dataObject = {x: 10, y: 10, name: 'Hello world!'};

    // the script to call
    // evaluates to drawCircle(10,10,'Hello world!');
    const script = "drawCircle(" + dataObject.x + "," + dataObject.y + ",'" + dataObject.name + "');";

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        csInterface.evalScript(script, (result) => {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

As expected, `circle()` calls `drawCircle()` just fine, and an ellipse appears in the document I'm working on.  However, executing a script/calling a function by concatenation feels very *wrong*. So in summary,

1. I would like some (neater) way of turning `dataObject` into a string and passing it to `drawCircle()` via `evalScript()`,
2. and I would like to return `dataObject` from `drawCircle()` and receive it back as an object.  Currently, returning an object only results in `"[object Object]"` as a return value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Javascript -> ExtendScript

The only way to pass objects from Javascript to ExtendScript is to send it as a JSON string with `JSON.stringify()`.

Yes, you are right about no `JSON.parse()` support, however, **you don't need to**.

You can still send the stringified object and will arrive to ExtendScript as an **object**.

```
const dataObject = {x: 10, y: 10, name: 'Hello world!'};
const script = "drawCircle(" + JSON.stringify(dataObject) + ")";
```

And then in ExtendScript, you can get way with doing something like this:

```
function drawCircle(obj) {
  var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];

  var radius = 10;
  var top = obj.y + 5;
  var left = obj.x - 5;

  var circle = layer.pathItems.ellipse(top, left, radius, radius);

  circle.name = obj.name;
  circle.filled = true;

  return true;
}
```

## ExtendScript -> Javascript

You will need this ExtendScript module, copied in the same folder as your jsx

[Link to Indiscripts ExtendScript JSON module](https://github.com/indiscripts/extendscript/blob/master/JSON/json.jsx)

Then include it with `#include 'json.jsx';` (or `//@include 'json.jsx'` to avoid linter errors) in the top of your jsx. This adds a JSON global function that provides two methods: `JSON.eval()` and `JSON.lave()`.

The method we need is `lave()` which allows you to stringify the object back to Javascript. Consider it a friendlier version of `JSON.stringify()`.

```
function drawCircle(obj) {
  var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];

  var radius = 10;
  var top = obj.y + 5;
  var left = obj.x - 5;

  // draw ellipse in layer
  var circle = layer.pathItems.ellipse(top, left, radius, radius);

  circle.name = obj.name;
  circle.filled = true;

  return JSON.lave(circle);
}
```

Then in javascript you can parse to an object yet again:

```
const dataObject = {x: 10, y: 10, name: 'Hello world!'};
const script = "drawCircle(" + JSON.stringify(dataObject) + ")";

csInterface.evalScript(script, (result) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(result));
});
```

I tested this in the latest CEP Runtime version (v9).

Comment: Thanks, had no idea about being able to pass stringified objects directly!  I also found a more general [JSON polyfill](https://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).  Both methods modify `$.global`, so I had to restart Illustrator to clear out `JSON.stringify()` before being able to use `JSON.lave()`.

Comment: If you have special characters inside the string you send, you need to ``escape`` them. 

If you only use ``decodeURIComponent``, it will not be covering some characters.

Especially if you need to support older versions, like Premiere 2019 for example...

(I know that ``escape`` is deprecated)